# Problem with coding multi-frame jump animation (GDScript)

Tags: python, animation, godot, gdscript

So I am a beginner programmer using GDScript and got stuck with playing jump animation. All my animations are like 2 frames and where easy to code, but my jump is multi-frame and I couldn't find a tutorial to help.

Also I'm not comfortable with anim.tree -s, I prefer to hard code them in.

My code (I know its basic):

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const SPD = 100
const GRV = 15
const JUMPF = -350
const SPD_B = 50

var valocity = Vector2(0,0)


func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        valocity.x = SPD
        $AnimatedSprite.play("walk")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        valocity.x = -SPD
        $AnimatedSprite.play("walk")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true
    else:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("idle")
    
    valocity.y = valocity.y + GRV
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_sprint") and Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        valocity.x = SPD + SPD_B
        $AnimatedSprite.play("run")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_sprint") and Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        valocity.x = -SPD + -SPD_B
        $AnimatedSprite.play("run")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up") and is_on_floor():
        valocity.y = JUMPF
    
    valocity = move_and_slide(valocity, Vector2.UP)
    
    valocity.x = lerp(valocity.x, 0, 0.3)
    
    
func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
    get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

SPD_B is speed bonus for sprint
Game is 2d platformer

I tried anim.tree but couldn't use it. It was to confusing. Also I tried to code it like other but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For your information `valocity.x = lerp(valocity.x, 0, 0.3)` is equivalent to `valocity.x *= 0.7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you would insert a line `$AnimatedSprite.play("jump")` or similar to play your jump animation. Correct?

Then the issue is that it gets replaced by the `"walk"` (or `"run"`) or `"idle"` animation the next frame.

Well, do you want those animations to play while the character is on the air (`not is_on_floor()`)? If you don't, then don't. usually the animations that play on the air are for jumping and falling, not for walking/running nor for idle.

That could be for example:

```
if is_on_floor():
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        valocity.x = SPD
        $AnimatedSprite.play("walk")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        valocity.x = -SPD
        $AnimatedSprite.play("walk")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true
    else:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("idle")

    # …
```

Now, presumably you still want air control (allow the player to move with the directions while it is on the air)… Thus I suggest to separate the animation concern.

So, one block of code will set the motion. And another will set the animations. Something like this:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
    valocity.x = SPD
elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
    valocity.x = -SPD

# …

if is_zero_approx(valocity.x):
    $AnimatedSprite.play("idle")
elif valocity.x > 0.0:
    $AnimatedSprite.play("walk")
    $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
elif valocity.x < 0.0:
    $AnimatedSprite.play("walk")
    $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true
```

The above code also makes it easy for the animation to change to `"idle"` automatically when the speed falls to zero. For example if you have some deceleration code such as `valocity.x *= 0.7` (which, notice, is not frame rate independent, but you get the idea).

And then it is easy to have a set of animations for the air and another for ground:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
    valocity.x = SPD
elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
    valocity.x = -SPD

# …

if is_on_floor():
    if is_zero_approx(valocity.x):
        $AnimatedSprite.play("idle")
    elif valocity.x > 0.0:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("walk")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
    elif valocity.x < 0.0:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("walk")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true

    # …
else:
    $AnimatedSprite.play("jump")
    # …
```

You can, of course, define a thresholds for using the `"run"` animation instead of the `"walk"` animation. For example:

```
if is_on_floor():
    if is_zero_approx(valocity.x):
        $AnimatedSprite.play("idle")
    elif valocity.x > SPD:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("run")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
    elif valocity.x < -SPD:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("run")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true
    elif valocity.x > 0.0:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("walk")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
    elif valocity.x < 0.0:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("walk")
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true
```

And of course, you would have to call `move_and_slide``, and also insert the code for jumps, gravity, and so on.